# Python: Converting binary data to hex array

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I have a binary file that contains one line of: abcd1234

In Python, reading this binary file using

```
filecontent = f_obj.read()
```

results in:

```
filecontent = b'abcd1234'
```

I want to store the result of `filecontent` into a byte array as:

```
array[0] = 0xab
array[1] = 0xcd
array[2] = 0x12
array[3] = 0x34
```

Is there a Python function that can do this conversion?

Comment: Isn't it already?  Can you not just decode the filecontent[x] into the byte code?

Comment: No it is not. I get instead 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34

Comment: Check out [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray).  Specifically `fromhex`.

Comment: Thank you! bytearray.fromhex() works. I will post the answer.

Comment: Your question title is wrong. You are not converting binary to hex - you are converting hex to binary (string `'ab'` is hex, whereas number `0xab` is binary)

Answer (score -1):

```
filecontent = filecontent.decode("utf-8") # to remove the b' ' from the string
filecontent = bytearray.fromhex(filecontent)
```